# Writing progress for worker threads reading from a queue

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I have a bunch of python threads reading from a queue, a-la https://gist.github.com/bsphere/f1e0a7d033dab2871c5c. I want to display progress every 10 seconds. This is the best I found till now, is there anything less verbose and more pythonic?

**Edit**: Sorry I wasn't clear - I'm not interested in a nice UI, I'm just interested in how do I interact with the threads correctly with no concurrency bugs to write the progress from the main thread while waiting for the workers to complete..

```
threads = []
for i in xrange(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS):
    t = MyThread()
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
live_threads = True
while live_threads:
    live_threads = False
    for t in threads:
        t.join(10)
        if t.isAlive():
            live_threads = True
            break
    logger.info("queue size: %s", q.qsize())
```

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm ? It seems quite popular on Kaggle, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. It's difficult to understand what's going on or what exactly you're asking. If you just want a more pythonic way of counting live threads, how about: `num_live = sum(t.isAlive() for t in threads)`  Then `time.sleep` a while and do it again. It's not clear to me what the queue size has to do with the number of live threads.

Comment: What constitutes "progress"? Interact with the threads in what way? How to you want to display the progress?